# H3 polyfill is skipping the areas near the boundary I am trying to polyfill. (Python)

Tags: h3

Is there a way to polyfill edge to edge or as much as possible (Res 8) without increasing the resolution.
[Black boundary is the polygon boundary I am trying to polyfill completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp78g.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why this happens

This happens because `polyfill` only returns cells whose centroid falls into the polygon.

#### What to do instead

In your case, you could use polyfill on a finer resolution and then use `h3_to_parent` to convert back to your desired resolution.

Keep in mind that this isn't guaranteed to cover the whole geometry. But in practice, using sufficiently fine resolution for `polyfill` usually does the trick (and the fact that some cells with only a tiny intersection might not generated is often even useful).

#### Example

Here is an example using [Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) and [H3-Pandas](https://github.com/DahnJ/H3-Pandas), but of course, the logic works with any implementation of the `H3` API.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import h3pandas

# Choose a random country boundary (Tanzania)
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')).iloc[1:2]
```

### Simple polyfill

```py
gdf.h3.polyfill_resample(2)
```

[image]

### "Finer" polyfill

```py
gdf.h3.polyfill_resample(4).h3.h3_to_parent_aggregate(2)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you achieve the same result by buffering the input polygon by the edge length (radius) for the desired h3 resolution?