# H3 - How to get the H3 index of all cells that are at least partially inside a bounding box/polygon

Tags: javascript, h3

I would like to get the h3 cell index of every cell that is at least partially within a bounding box. I have been using `h3.polygonToCells()` but it appears that `h3.polygonToCells()` only returns cells that are mostly within the bounding box (polygon).

This how the coverage looks over central London, with resolution 3:

```
const coords = [
    [51.55, -0.01],
    [51.45, -0.01],
    [51.45, -0.16],
    [51.55, -0.16],
];

let RESOLUTION_LEVEL = 3;
const cells = h3.polygonToCells(coords, RESOLUTION_LEVEL, false);

console.log("cells", cells); // returns an array of 0 items
```

[image: picture showing map with H3 resolution 7 - no cells returned]

And now the same area, with resolution 7:

```
RESOLUTION_LEVEL = 7;
const cells = h3.polygonToCells(coords, RESOLUTION_LEVEL, false);

console.log("cells", cells); // returns an array of 26 items
```

[image: picture showing map with H3 resolution 3 - many cells returned, all with a majority of the cell inside the bounding box]

How do I get all the H3 cell indexes for the whole bounding box?

Comment: You can use the approach outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72967263/1785661). It's written in Python, bu the exact same approach will work in javascript, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
h3.polygonToCells(coordinates, resolution, [isGeoJson])
```

provides the hexagons in such a way that the center of the hexagon should be inside your bounded area.

If you want to keep the inside hexagons only, you can further use this function to achieve that:

```
h3.cellToBoundary(h3Index)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however instead of getting cells that are entirely within the bounding box that you have provided here, I would actually like to get the h3 cell index of every cell that is at least partially within a bounding box (i.e. including cells that have only a couple of square metres inside the bounding box.)

Comment: You can get all the neighbor cells of the current rendered cells.

```const hexagons = h3.polygonToCells(coordinates, resolution, [isGeoJson]); // Returns h3 Indexes

const multiPolygon = hexagons.map((hexagon) => cellToBoundary(hexagon)); // Convert the h3 Indexes to Polygon
const hexagonMultiPolygons = multiPolygon.flat().map((polygon) => {
  return latLngToCell(
    polygon[0],
    polygon[1],
    layer?.resolution || DEFAULT_RESOLUTION
  );
}); // Get the neighbor cells from the polygon's coordinates

const layerData = [...new Set([...hexagons, ...hexagonMultiPolygons])];
```